# How to plot polygons with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an old R code plotting a BMI-plot using Rbase

This is how the old code looks

```
# BMI-Classes
Gewichtsklassen <- c(0, 18.5, 25, 30, 35, 40, 100)

# nice colors
Farben <- c("skyblue4", "darkgreen", "yellow", "orange", "red", "darkred", "black")

# 100 bodyheights from 1,4m to 2,2m
Koerpergroesse <- seq(1.4, 2.2, length = 100)

# Function to get the BMI class borders
# for any body height
bmi.k <- function(groesse, konstant) {
  return(groesse^2 * konstant)
}

# For polygons, we need to give start end enpoint
# so we reverse all body heights
KoerpergroesseREV <- rev(Koerpergroesse)
# calculate all class borders
Klasse1a <- bmi.k(Koerpergroesse, Gewichtsklassen[1])
Klasse1b <- rev(bmi.k(Koerpergroesse, Gewichtsklassen[2]))
Klasse2a <- bmi.k(Koerpergroesse, Gewichtsklassen[2])
Klasse2b <- rev(bmi.k(Koerpergroesse, Gewichtsklassen[3]))
Klasse3a <- bmi.k(Koerpergroesse, Gewichtsklassen[3])
Klasse3b <- rev(bmi.k(Koerpergroesse, Gewichtsklassen[4]))
Klasse4a <- bmi.k(Koerpergroesse, Gewichtsklassen[4])
Klasse4b <- rev(bmi.k(Koerpergroesse, Gewichtsklassen[5]))
Klasse5a <- bmi.k(Koerpergroesse, Gewichtsklassen[5])
Klasse5b <- rev(bmi.k(Koerpergroesse, Gewichtsklassen[6]))
Klasse6a <- bmi.k(Koerpergroesse, Gewichtsklassen[6])
Klasse6b <- rev(bmi.k(Koerpergroesse, Gewichtsklassen[7]))
Klasse7a <- bmi.k(Koerpergroesse, Gewichtsklassen[7])
Klasse7b <- rev(bmi.k(Koerpergroesse, Gewichtsklassen[8]))

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# lets plot the basic plot
plot(Koerpergroesse, bmi.k(Koerpergroesse, 18), type="n", 
     xlim=c(1.60, 1.99), ylim=c(40, 125), 
     xaxt="n", yaxt="n", 
     cex.axis=1.4, cex.lab=1.3, cex.main=1.7, 
     xlab="Größe [in m]", ylab="Gewicht [in kg]", main="Body Mass Index")
# add polygons for each class
polygon(c(Koerpergroesse, KoerpergroesseREV), c(Klasse1a, Klasse1b), col=Farben[1])
polygon(c(Koerpergroesse, KoerpergroesseREV), c(Klasse2a, Klasse2b), col=Farben[2])
polygon(c(Koerpergroesse, KoerpergroesseREV), c(Klasse3a, Klasse3b), col=Farben[3])
polygon(c(Koerpergroesse, KoerpergroesseREV), c(Klasse4a, Klasse4b), col=Farben[4])
polygon(c(Koerpergroesse, KoerpergroesseREV), c(Klasse5a, Klasse5b), col=Farben[5])
polygon(c(Koerpergroesse, KoerpergroesseREV), c(Klasse6a, Klasse6b), col=Farben[6])
polygon(c(Koerpergroesse, KoerpergroesseREV), c(Klasse7a, Klasse7b), col=Farben[7])

# add a Gitter
box()
grid(lty="dotdash" ,col="darkgrey")
abline(v=seq(1.65, 1.95, by=0.1), h=seq(50, 110, by=20), lty="dotted", col="grey") 

# Legendenbox
legend(x="bottomright", inset=0.005, 
       legend=c("Untergewicht", "Normalgewicht", "Präadipositas",
                "Adipositas Grad I", "Adipositas Grad II", "Adipositas Grad III"),
       col=Farben, lwd=6, bg="skyblue")

# X-Achse big ticks
axis(1, at=format(seq(1.60, 2, by=0.1), nsmall=2), 
     labels=format(seq(1.60, 2, by=0.1), nsmall=2), cex.axis=1.5)
# X-Achse small gray ticks
axis(1, at=seq(1.65, 2, by=0.1), cex.axis=1.2, col.axis="grey")
# Y-Achse Ticks
axis(2, at=seq(40, 120, by=10), cex.axis=1.5)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So this works fine and gives me a nice plot like this

[image: BMI plot]

So, now I am trying to plot this pic with ggplot2.

I put all data into a data.frame as a "long table"

```
df1 <- data.frame(Koerpergroesse, Wert=Klasse1a, Class="K1")
df2 <- data.frame(Koerpergroesse, Wert=Klasse2a, Class="K2")
df3 <- data.frame(Koerpergroesse, Wert=Klasse3a, Class="K3")
df4 <- data.frame(Koerpergroesse, Wert=Klasse4a, Class="K4")
df5 <- data.frame(Koerpergroesse, Wert=Klasse5a, Class="K5")
df6 <- data.frame(Koerpergroesse, Wert=Klasse6a, Class="K6")
df7 <- data.frame(Koerpergroesse, Wert=Klasse7a, Class="K7")
df <- rbind(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7 )
```

If I call ggplot with geom_polygon like this:

```
ggplot(df) + 
  aes(x=Koerpergroesse, y=Wert, fill=Class) +  
  geom_polygon()
```

I get a plot like this:

[image: geom_polygon looks wrong]

If I use geom_area(), the plot looks even weirder

```
ggplot(df) + aes(x=Koerpergroesse, y=Wert, fill=Class) +  
  geom_area()
```

[image: geom_area looks wrong, too]

The Y-axis seems to be wrong, as K2 for example starts at near 500 and goes up to 1250. These number are not in the dataset:

```
summary(df)

> summary(df)
 Koerpergroesse      Wert           Class          
 Min.   :1.4    Min.   :  0.00   Length:700        
 1st Qu.:1.6    1st Qu.: 60.83   Class :character  
 Median :1.8    Median : 91.63   Mode  :character  
 Mean   :1.8    Mean   :116.95                     
 3rd Qu.:2.0    3rd Qu.:138.66                     
 Max.   :2.2    Max.   :484.00
```

So, what am I doing wrong?

How would I plot my BMI plot with ggplot?

**EDIT:**

Thx for your comments and answers. Although I tagged another answer as the "right one" (because its so simple), the solution to my specific code was to add the "reversed" data to the long table, too

Like this:

```
### Tidy Data
# bereite "long table" vor
df1 <- data.frame(Gross=c(Koerpergroesse, KoerpergroesseREV), Wert=c(Klasse1a, Klasse1b), Class="K1")
df2 <- data.frame(Gross=c(Koerpergroesse, KoerpergroesseREV), Wert=c(Klasse2a, Klasse2b), Class="K2")
df3 <- data.frame(Gross=c(Koerpergroesse, KoerpergroesseREV), Wert=c(Klasse3a, Klasse3b), Class="K3")
df4 <- data.frame(Gross=c(Koerpergroesse, KoerpergroesseREV), Wert=c(Klasse4a, Klasse4b), Class="K4")
df5 <- data.frame(Gross=c(Koerpergroesse, KoerpergroesseREV), Wert=c(Klasse5a, Klasse5b), Class="K5")
df6 <- data.frame(Gross=c(Koerpergroesse, KoerpergroesseREV), Wert=c(Klasse6a, Klasse6b), Class="K6")
df7 <- data.frame(Gross=c(Koerpergroesse, KoerpergroesseREV), Wert=c(Klasse7a, Klasse7b), Class="K7")
# schreibe alles ins Datenframe df
df <- rbind(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7 )


ggplot(df) + aes(x=Gross, y=Wert, fill=Class) +  
  geom_polygon()+
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1.55, 2.05), ylim = c(35, 125), expand = FALSE)
```

This works and looks as the original plot.
(I need to change colors and add a legendbox, but thats no problem)

[image]

Comment: `graphics::polygon` (base graphics) and `ggplot2::geom_polygon` are similar in that you are needing to provide the "current" Class vector and the reverse of the "previous" Class vector in order to close the polygon.

Comment: But How would I prepare the data? How would aes() Look like?

Comment: If you could provide a minimal reproducible example, it would allow us to assist more effectively without having to make assumptions. Providing the output of head() for each of df1 through df7 should suffice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple implementation in ggplot would be to use the BMI formula BMI = weight / height^2 to create a filled contour.

```r
library(ggplot2)

expand.grid(weight = seq(30, 130, 0.1), height = seq(1.5, 2.1, 0.01)) |>
  ggplot(aes(height, weight)) +
  geom_contour_filled(aes(z = weight/height^2), color = "black",
                      breaks = c(0, 18.5, 25, 30, 35, 40, 100)) +
  scale_fill_manual("BMI", 
                    values = rev(c("#8b0000", "red", "#ffa500", "yellow",
                                   "#006400", "#4a708b"))) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1.55, 2.05), ylim = c(35, 125), expand = FALSE) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 20) +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.9, 0.2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Basic flow of my code:

- For each `K#`, identify the *next* `K#` so that we can derive the "bottom" of the polygon;
- For each `K#` again, interpolate the "other" `y` values from this group's `x`/`y` pair, and then reverse the x/y values;
- Combine with the original `df`, so that now all of `K1` has all of `K1`'s `Koerpergroesse` x `Wert`, and then just as many rows with `K2`'s `Wert` interpolated values, reversed
- I have a `Gewichte` frame that provides a good mapping of your `K#` to the words you want in the legend ... it's easier to then group using `fill=ClassTxt` so that the legend is just... right. For this, I do filter out `K7`, since ggplot is going to show it even if it is off-screen
- Note, if we use `scale_x_continuous(limits=..)` (same for `y`), we get "clipping", meaning we will have incomplete polygons. Instead, we use `coord_cartesian` where we can have the polygons be continuous with all of its points, even those that are outside of the plot's visible limits.

```r
Gewichte <- data.frame(
  ClassTxt = factor(
    c("Untergewicht", "Normalgewicht", "Präadipositas", "Adipositas Grad I",
      "Adipositas Grad II", "Adipositas Grad III", "UNK"),
    levels = c("Untergewicht", "Normalgewicht", "Präadipositas", "Adipositas Grad I",
      "Adipositas Grad II", "Adipositas Grad III", "UNK")),
  Class = paste0("K", 1:7),
  col = Farben
)
# names(Farben) <- paste0("K", 1:7)
slice_head(df, n = 1, by = Class) %>%
  transmute(Class, OthClass = lead(Class)) %>%
  left_join(df, by = "Class") %>%
  mutate(
    Wert = if (is.na(OthClass[1])) Inf else {
      rev(approx(df$Koerpergroesse[df$Class==OthClass[1]],
             df$Wert[df$Class==OthClass[1]],
             xout = Koerpergroesse, na.rm = TRUE)$y) },
    Koerpergroesse = rev(Koerpergroesse),
    .by = Class) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-OthClass) %>%
  bind_rows(df) %>%
  left_join(Gewichte, by = "Class") %>%
  filter(Class != "K7") %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(aes(x = Koerpergroesse, y = Wert, fill = ClassTxt)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1.60, 1.99), ylim = c(40, 125)) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = NULL, values = setNames(Gewichte$col, Gewichte$ClassTxt)) +
  labs(title = "Body Mass Index", x = "Größe [in m]", y = "Gewicht [in kg]")
```

This ggplot output:

[image: ggplot of layered BMI]

The base-graphics you provided produces

[image: base plot of the same data]

(Pretty close.)

I'll leave the rest of the aesthetics (grid, inset legend, axis breaks/labels) to you.